# How to lazy load tabs in TabView?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, winui-3, winui

Is there a built-in mechanism to lazy load tab view items in TabView?
Other than implementing something myself by a combination of using tab selected event and load the content.

Comment: No, you need to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is not. I guess you need to implement it yourself.

One way to do this:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="Start" />
    <TabView
        Grid.Row="1"
        TabItemsSource="{x:Bind LazyLoadingTabs, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> LazyLoadingTabs = new();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                {
                    LazyLoadingTabs.Add(i.ToString());
                });

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your sample does not load the tab item content in lazy way :)

Comment: Sorry James. You are right. I was in a hurry when I posted the answer and didn't think clearly about your requirements.